# C# sort custom class list

Tags: c#, sorting

I have that class

```
public class MyItem
{
    public Order OrderItem { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

the `Status` property can have values `Error`, `Pending`, `Success`

I want to sort the `List<MyItem>()` object basing on the `Status` property.

I know that I can replace the type of the `Status` property from `string` to `int` and then instead of `Error`, `Pending`, `Success` values I can have `1`,`2`,`3` and then the sort operation is simple. But I'm wondering how to do it if we must do the sorting on basing on the `string` type property.

Possible order:

`Error`, `Pending`, `Success` or `Success`, `Pending`, `Error`

how to do it by using LINQ ?

Comment: Why strings and not enums?

Comment: You can write a custom `IComparer<string>` but, like @PLB says, why not use an enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to implement the `IComparable<T>` interface. Implementing this interface on your `MyItem` class will ensure that when ordering a list of `MyItem` instances, the ordering as specified in the `CompareTo` method will be used. For your use case, this would result in code like this:

```
public class MyItem : IComparable<MyItem>
{
    public string OrderItem { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(MyItem other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (other.Status == this.Status)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var statusAsInt = this.Status == "Error" ? 0 : (this.Status == "Pending" ? 1 : 2);
        var otherStatusAsInt = other.Status == "Error" ? 0 : (other.Status == "Pending" ? 1 : 2);

        if (statusAsInt == otherStatusAsInt)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return statusAsInt < otherStatusAsInt ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myItems = new List<MyItem> { new MyItem { Status = "Pending" }, new MyItem { Status = "Error" }, new MyItem { Status = "Success " } };

        myItems.Sort();

        foreach (var myItem in myItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myItem.Status);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use an `enum` instead which by default gives each status an integer value e.g.

```
public enum Status
{
    Success,
    Pending,
    Error
}

var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Status);
// sort by Success, Pending and then Error
var sortedList = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Status);
// sort by Error, Pending, Success
```

You can convert your existing strings to `enum` pretty easily:

```
var status = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), statusString);
```

Comment: I've done that already but I'm wondering about the string case

Comment: @Tony if you *had* to compare `string`'s you would need to write your own `IComparer<T>` class or make your `MyItem` class implement `IComparable<T>`. However, I would definitely push for switching to `enum` in this case, it's the right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Its better to parse to an `enum` but, you could make a custom comparer,

```
var customComparer = Comparer<string>.Create((x, y) =>
    {
        ...
    });
```

You can than pass the the comparer into sort and order by functions, like this,

```
var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Status, customComparer);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a dictionary which reflects the required ordering

```
Dictionary<string, int> ordering = new Dictionary<string, int> {
  { "Error", 1 },
  { "Pending", 2 },
  ...
}

var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x => ordering[x.Status]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to change the type of Status and replace the String by an enum. You can then choose the order you want by assigning values to the different members of your enum, or directly order this member as desired by your order method, and keep a readable property.

Answer (score 1):

As the orders happen to be alphabetical, you can do a simple

```
var result = myList.OrderBy(item => item.Status);
```

or

```
var result = myList.OrderByDescending(item => item.Status);
```

However, if you rename "Success" as "Complete", then it'll break, in which case I'd recommend one of the suggested `enum` answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the Enum option but given that it's not your preferred option you might try the following:

You can implement **`IComparable<MyItem>`** in your class **`MyItem`**

Over there implement your logic of ordering according to the Status property. If two status are equal you can even then order by OrderItem, if that suits you.

If you need an example feel free to say so

Answer (score 0):

You can pass .OrderBy() a method that weights the strings using a switch like this:

```
     List<MyItem> lst = new List<MyItem>();

     lst.Add(new MyItem() { Status = "Pending" });
     lst.Add(new MyItem() { Status = "Error" });
     lst.Add(new MyItem() { Status = "Invalid String" });
     lst.Add(new MyItem() { Status = "Success" });

     var ascList =
        lst.OrderBy((x) => { switch (x.Status) { case "Error": return 0; case "Pending": return 1; case "Success": return 3; default: return 4; } });

     var descList =
        lst.OrderByDescending((x) => { switch (x.Status) { case "Error": return 0; case "Pending": return 1; case "Success": return 3; default: return 4; } });

     Console.WriteLine("Asc\n===");
     foreach (MyItem mi in ascList)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(mi.Status);
     }

     Console.WriteLine("\nDesc\n====");
     foreach (MyItem mi in descList)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(mi.Status);
     }
  }
```